# WinZip Courier automatically zipping email attachments

Tags: shell-scripting, windows-registry, msi

I am trying to create a pre-configured MSI file for WinZip Courier 6 (latest version) within a CMD script (eventually deploying on SCCM).

The main MSI property to turn off automatic zipping is "AlwaysZipAttachments" which it set to "0".

Now according to [the official WinZip Courier site](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/307/), the "0" value only allows the User to be able to turn the feature off!

So this does not completely turn auto zipping off!

Has anybody came across a solution to turn auto zipping off through with editing/adding registry keys, or adding an MSI property to the MSI Courier file?

I hope this is clear.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3228589443-4080523269-2427214327-25808\Software\Nico Mak Computing\WinZip Courier]
"SendItem"="0"
```